How to Handle Interest Tags in Multiple Languages in Financial Services Cloud
I'm looking for some help with managing Interest Tags in the Financial Services Cloud, especially since our team works in a multilingual setup.
Here are my main questions:

Do Interest Tags in Financial Services Cloud support translations? If yes, how can we set this up?
If translations aren't supported, what are some best practices for handling Interest Tags in a multilingual environment?

Any tips or experiences you can share would be super helpful!
Thanks a lot!
